# can PHP and node.js run on the same server

Tags: php, json, node.js

I have a web application with Apache and PHP on the back end. I am in the process of enhancing this with many new features and considering using node.js for the new work.

First of all, can PHP and node.js co exist on the same machine? I do not see why not.
Second, can I just call node.js code directly from Javascript and return JSON back?

Comment: Call Node code directly from Javascript on the client side? Not quite; Node, like PHP, works over HTTP.

Comment: I understand that. Actually to be correct, node is not limited to HTTP....My question is, similar to how JS on the client side calls php scripts on the server side, can JS on the client side call node.js scripts? Or does it have to go through a middle tier such as a application server?

Comment: Node comes with an HTTP request handler, but you're supposed to run a proper web server in front of that (such as nginx).

Comment: I understand this is an old question but the answers so far have been lacklustre.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, and yes. Node and Apache / PHP can co-exist on a single server.

The only issue you are likely to run into is that they cannot both listen on the same *port*. HTTP, by default, runs on port 80 and only one process can "listen" on a single port at any one time. You may therefore have to run the Node app on a different port (for example, 8080), which could bring in difficulties if any of your target users are restricted to only port 80.

Comment: I have a simple workaround for this. I use php in order to provide REST API to my React DOM. Basically php is my logic (model and controllers) and React my views (and routes, of course). The advantage of using that kind of approach is that performance will increase (APIs can be cached) and every third part system will communicate with you using an API that you have to develop only once. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 19):

You can run node and PHP on same server, and even on the same port. The key is to use a server like nginx in front listening on port 80, set up PHP in Nginx as you normally would (using php-fpm) and set up your Node instance to listen locally on some high port like 8081.

Then just configure nginx to proxy all the Node requests through to localhost:8081 using the directory name as a filter.  You're essentially setting up nginx to treat Node requests a bit like it treats PHP requests: it forwards them off to some other daemon then handles the response as it comes back.  Nginx is great at this.  It will add a layer of security and it will boost performance because it's so good at managing many connections at once even when the backend doesn't.

Another benefit of this is that you can have multiple separate Node instances on different domains too, and use regular nginx rules to handle it all. You can also run it alongside other app servers like apps written in Go.

You'd benefit from Nginx's configurability, its SSL and HTTP/2 support and huge speed in serving static files, and not having to serve static files from your Node app (if you don't want to).

Comment: I can't imagine this topic without this answer ... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can do it. If you server is an Ubuntu or Debian, follow these steps:

1. Open your terminal an write:

   ```
   sudo curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
   sudo apt-get install nodejs
   ```
2. If curl is not installed on your server:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install curl
   ```
3. To your Node.js application not stop when you exit the Terminal without shutting down your instance, use a package called [Forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever).

   ```
   npm install -g forever
   ```
4. If your site is uploaded and NPM and Forever are configured correctly, it is time to start the Node.js instance. If you’re using Express.js, run the following command to start a Forever instance:

   ```
   forever start ./path/to/your/project
   ```
5. In the above command you'll notice I am feeding the ./bin/www script because that is what npm start launches for Express.js. Be sure to change the script to whatever your launch script is.

By default, the website (nodejs) is running at http://localhost:3000 which isn't ideal for remote visitors. We want to be able to access our site from a domain name processed by Apache. In your Apache VirtualHost file, you might have something that looks like the following:

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</virtualhost>
```

We are telling Apache to create a proxy that will get our Node.js http://localhost:3000 site every time the www.yousite.com domain name is hit. All assets and pages will use the www.yoursite.com path instead of http://localhost:3000 leading everyone to believe the website is being served no differently than any other.

However, by default, the Apache proxy modules are not enabled. You must run the following two commands if the modules are not already enabled:

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
```

You may be required to restart Apache after enabling these modules.

I get this information on [The Poliglot Developer](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/01/run-nodejs-application-lamp-stack-server/).

Answer (score -2):

Yeh, if you use php to serve javascript pages to clients the javascript code can use AJAX requests to access routes exposed from your node server.