# What server side technology is the webapp deeyoon.com based on?

Tags: web-applications, server-side, opentok, videochat, tokbox

I entered the site's url in the builthwith[dot]com site to see what core technology the website is built with but I did not see a reference to php, python, ruby or any other familiar web application languages that I am aware of. Please excuse my ignorance, I'm essentially trying to figure what server side technology the website is built with.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it uses PHP, if you view the page source the links end in .php. It also is using JavaScript and is run on a Ubuntu server.

Comment: the page source of the home page? I didn't see the link that ends in .php . The builtwith site reports that deeyoon makes use of socket.io which tells me that javascript/nodejs is running on the server side to some extent

Comment: <link type="text/css" href="http://chat.deeyoon.com/cometchatcss.php" rel="stylesheet" charset="utf-8"> This link is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: How is the site able to use both PHP and Javascript/nodejs in the server side?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730008/can-php-and-node-js-run-on-the-same-server Yes it possible. The only way to be completely sure what its running would be to email them. -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770506/how-to-identify-which-server-side-script-language-is-using-with-a-web-site

Comment: That concept is bizarre to me, multiple languages in the server-side...do you know any goodreads/tutorials that sheds light on this concept?