# Electron | Error invoking remote method 'some-name'

Tags: reactjs, electron, ipc, ipcrenderer, ipcmain

I'm trying to implement in my electron application.

In `main.ts` :

```
  ipcMain.handle('some-name', async (event, someArgument) => {
    console.log("--------------------")
    console.log(someArgument)
    console.log("--------------------")
    return true
  })
```

In a React.Component, I got :

```
import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron'
...
ipcRenderer.invoke('some-name',"sadkjasd").then((result) => {
      console.log("finished")
    })
```

And it's giving me error, saying :

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error invoking remote method 'some-name': No handler registered for 'some-name'
    at EventEmitter.o.invoke (electron/js2c/renderer_init.js:71)
```

How can I register an event ?

I'm actually trying to figure out IPC of GitHub desktop, that's one cool electron app :

- [ipcMain](https://github.com/maifeeulasad/desktop/blob/017941dc2559bb3fe5279f8424dc36296c999c31/app/src/main-process/main.ts#L461)
- [ipcRenderer](https://github.com/maifeeulasad/desktop/blob/017941dc2559bb3fe5279f8424dc36296c999c31/app/src/ui/cloning-repository.tsx#L22)

Comment: You could try using `on` and `send` in electron by referring to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67436511/14176786

Comment: I am not sure if you would use `on` or `send` or instead you only want to use `invoke`

Comment: `send` and `on` pair didn't worked... it didn't triggered... that's why i was foing through doc again and found this code : `invoke` and `handle` pair... it raised error.. now i'm all confused..

Comment: I had that kind of error message too `Error occurred in handler for 'channelName': No handler registered for 'channelName'` what worked in my case was to close the app and start it again. You may also want to take a look at the [Inter-Process Communications guide](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) from the doc

Comment: @Darkosphere omg ive been sitting here for hours trying to debug this, looking over the documentation over and over again, yet all i needed to do was restart the app... fml